# lenses for tuple extension?

Tags: haskell, lenses

[Control.Lens.Tuple](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.17.1/docs/Control-Lens-Tuple.html) defines lenses to access elements of tuples. For example

```
class Field3 s t a b | s -> a, t -> b, s b -> t, t a -> s where
  -- | Access the 3rd field of a tuple.
  _3 :: Lens s t a b

  -- >>> (1,2,3)^._3
  -- 3
  --
  -- >>> _3 .~ "hello" $ (1,2,3)
  -- (1,2,"hello")
```

The setter `_3 .~` returns a tuple with the third element changed, to a different type in this example.

For class `Field3` there's instances defined for tuples with three or more elements. Not for pairs/two-ples, because what would a getter get?

But if a setter can change the type of the nth element, why couldn't it change the type to a different arity of tuple?

```
  -- >>> _3 .~ "hello" $ (1,2)
  -- (1,2,"hello")
```

That is, a setter `_3 .~` setting the third element by extending a two-ple.

```
instance Field3 (a,b) (a,b,c') Dummy c' where
  _3 k ~(a,b) = k undefined <&> \c' -> (a,b,c')
```

In which `Dummy` and `undefined` is some place-holder type and value for the non-existent third element of the incoming two-ple.

After extending to arity 3, lens `_3` works as usual; also lenses `_1, _2` obey the lens laws throughout.

Q1. Will this work for a setter?
    (of course it won't for an updater/`over`)

Q2. If so, is there some way to make it ill-typed to try `view`ing the non-existent 3rd element?

Q3. If a setter won't work, could there be an `extend` operator that will achieve the effect? (Presumably using a different functor.)

Perhaps the instance could be this

```
instance Field3 (a,b) (a,b,c') (a,b) c' where
  _3 k ~(a,b) = k (a,b) <&> \c' -> (a,b,c')
```

Such that `view` would return a weirdly typed result, and `over` could potentially build the third element from the first two.

Comment: I kinda got this working, in the sense `_3 .~ "hello" $ (1,2)` was accepted and produced the result I wanted. But the instance wasn't accepted: inconsistent with the proper instance, for FunDep `t a -> s` -- which is quite correct. I just suppressed that FunDep on the class.

Comment: If all you want is a setter `(a, b) -> c -> (a, b, c)`, what is the rest of the lens infrastructure getting you that `_3' = uncurry (,,)` doesn't? Genericity of some sort?

Comment: My two-ple is of course deeply nested inside all sorts of other structures I'm lensing into. So I want something I can compose as a lens. Then your `_3'` is not that. I see no Functor.

Comment: It's a setter. It doesn't need to operate over an arbitrary `Functor`; its `Functor` is `Identity`.

If you have a van Laarhoven lens `forall f. Functor f => ((a, b) -> f (a, b, c)) -> s -> f t`, you should be able to compose that with `c -> (a, b) -> Identity (a, b, c)` to get a setter in the style you want for your larger structure. That's the beauty of van Laarhoven lenses; you can do an awful lot with plain old composition.

Comment: Sorry @user11228628, I'm not seeing it. Using my def'n `set _3 "hello" (1, 2)` gives `(1,2,"hello")`, and the type of `_3` has a Functor required in its constraints. Using your def'n `set _3' "hello" (1,2)` is ill-typed, and the type of `_3'`  doesn't mention Functor. `set` would introduce the `Identity` Functor.

Answer (score 2):

In the van Laarhoven lens formulation, a optic is just a higher-order function that takes an action on a smaller structure to an action on a larger structure. These functions can be composed, and then used with the sugar provided in the `lens` package to make calling them mindless. But they can also just be called.

Let's say you have this:

```
bigStructure :: (Int, (Int, (Int, Int)))
bigStructure = (0, (1, (2, 3)))
```

And you want to append a `10` to the innermost pair. That's an action on that pair, which is a smaller piece of the big structure.

```
mk3ple :: c -> (a, b) -> (a, b, c)
mk3ple = flip $ uncurry (,,)
```

So `_2 . _2` is a lens focusing on that innermost pair—in other words, it's a function that takes actions on that innermost pair to actions on the big structure. So let's just... pass `mk3ple` to it (`over` does this; it just takes care of some `Identity` busywork for us):

```
over (_2 . _2) (mk3ple 10) bigStructure
```

And there you are—a setter (conceptual, that is; not a literal `Setter`) for `bigStructure` that uses whatever lenses you need to focus on the tuple.

---

Of course, if you'd rather have the tuple-appender be an actual lens with a getter and everything, you can certainly do that too! Just think of unit as a part of every tuple, and write:

```
mk3ple' :: Lens (a, b) (a, b, c) () c
mk3ple' = lens (const ()) (uncurry (,,))

set (_2 . _2 . mk3ple') 10 bigStructure
```

Comment: "the tuple-appender be an actual lens with a getter and everything" yes: once the two-ple is extended to a three-ple, then get/set the 3rd element. Then `mk3ple'` is not that. `view mk3ple' (1,2,3)` is ill typed. `view mk3ple' (1,2)` is well-typed, but always returns dummy `()`. `set mk3ple' "hello" (1,2,3)` is ill-typed. So I think to avoid corrupting the FunDep `t a -> s` on class `Field3`, create another class that is like it but without that FunDep, with a method that is as per `_3` for the `instance Field3x (a,b,c) (a,b,c') ...` but per my O.P. for `instance Field3x (a,b) (a,b,c') ...`.

Comment: I want to use the same-named lens for every access. Because lenses. Otherwise I need to use one name once only to extend, then a different name for `view`/`over`. That'll be hard to read and brittle code: I can't readily refactor if it resequences the actions.

Comment: "Otherwise I need to use one name once only to extend, then a different name for `view`/`over`." Well, they *are* different lenses. Technically, `mk3ple'` is not law-abiding, since `mk3ple' pure = pure` is not satisfied. But `_3` is law-abiding. That's why I presented the `over` solution first, because what you want isn't a perfect fit for the lens pattern. I'm not sure it's a great idea to make a type class where some instances are law-abiding and others aren't, but it's your code!

Comment: (To be clear, this is not just a flaw of my `mk3ple'`; no lens—or even setter—that behaves as you originally describe can be law-abiding. For setters, the relevant law is `over l id = id`. But if your optic `l` converts two-ples to three-ples, then the action of `id` over it can't be `id`: the input type of `over l id` is a two-ple but the output is a three-ple.)

Comment: Also, the answer to the question, "should I fight the type system tooth and nail so I can give two things the same name" is always, "Yes, of course you should. What could possibly go wrong?"

Comment: My expectation of the compiler/type system is that if the code compiles, it is well-typed. So in what sense am I "fight[ing] the type system"? Oh yes: GHC compiles methods but then you find they're unusable/there's no non-bottom values that inhabit the inferred type. It's rich lensists throwing "law-abiding" at this: EKmett seems to delight in breaking the vanLaarhoven laws. So I'll work on a solution that's more law-abiding. Already I can do `over l id = id`.